# Android - Arraylist returning null outside for loop

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm getting the `List<String> resultList` response as empty in ResponseFinal log.But inside the loop the response is showing items in **resultList**

I don't understand why resultlist is returning empty outside the loop.Please help

```
public List<String> getParseJson(String sName)
{
    final List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String name=sName.replace(" ", "%20");
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constants.BASE_URL + "/suggest_item/items/"+name +"/"+ Constants.API_KEY,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Result handling
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Item");

                    for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        System.out.println( predsJsonArray.get(i).toString());
                        resultList.add(predsJsonArray.get(i).toString());
                        Log.e("Response",resultList.toString());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSOn", "Cannot process JSON results", e);
                }
           }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Error handling
                System.out.println(error.toString());

           }
     });

     // Adding request to request queue
     Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(stringRequest);

     Log.e("ResponseFinal",resultList.toString());
     return resultList;
}
```

My log :

```
E/Response: [1660309, 1660410]
E/ResponseFinal: []
```

Comment: what does your json response look like? and what does `Log.e("ResponseFinal",resultList.toString());` actually print to logcat?

Comment: Return `null` OR empty list ??

Comment: Have you got the values from outside the for loop ? Even I'm also having same problem. I'm retrieving data from firebase in onDataChange method. I defined the arraylist at class level only. All values are saved in the arraylist inside the onDataChange method and the log shows perfectly but when I tried to show the log outside the onDataChange method then it shows null pointer exception in logcat. My arraylist is empty. What's the issue behind this ? I tried with string array,stringbuilder too.... @nithin

Answer (score 2):

declare List before `oncreate()` (defining the `resultList` at class level)

```
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning list before response is coming that's why you are getting empty list. You can do something like below code which can get you list after response.

**Step 1:** Make a method name it `onSuccess(List<String> list)` with your `getParseJson()` method

```
public void onSuccess(List<String> list){
  // do your code here after getting the list
}

//make this method as void
public void getParseJson(String sName){
    //your code which you have already implemented
}
```

**Step 2:** call the above method from `onResponse()` method which is declared inside your `getParseJson()` method as follows:

```
 @Override
   public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Result handling
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Item");

                    for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        System.out.println( predsJsonArray.get(i).toString());
                        resultList.add(predsJsonArray.get(i).toString());
                        Log.e("Response",resultList.toString());
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSOn", "Cannot process JSON results", e);
                }

              //call here
              onSuccess(resultList);
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you are calling `getParseJson()` from another class then call it as follows:

```
//If you are having paramaterized constructor then you can give parameter 
 new YourClassName(){
     @Override
     public void success(List<String> list) {
            // do your code here after getting the list
     }
 }.getParseJson(String response);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why `resultList` is returning empty outside the loop...

It is empty because your request runs asynchronously. So, you create your request along with response listeners, pass it to the `Volley` and then `getParseJson()` returns empty list - because request wasn't performed yet, and the other code will  not wait for it to perform. After that, when request is performed (and it's performed **asynchronously**), your response listener adds the JSON values to the `resultList` but it's too late.

Rewrite your code so it handles the asynchronous nature of Volley requests.

Answer (score 1):

The list in which you added is a copy and has scope only inside  public void onResponse(String response). Hence, the actual list is empty as it was when defined. so, the final log displays empty.